# Solve an equation for a variable

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can anyone please help me solve the following equation for x? Or, if it's already on the site, could you point me to it or tell me what terms to search for?

$$y = C_1e^{-C_2(1-C_3x)}+C_4\sqrt x$$

I tried taking the natural log of both sides and rearranging things:

$$ln(y) = ln(C_1e^{-C_2(1-C_3x)}+C_4\sqrt x)$$

$$ln(y) = ln\left(\sqrt x\left(\frac {C_1e^{-C_2(1-C_3x)}} {\sqrt x}+C_4\right)\right)$$

But I don't think it's getting me anywhere - I still have an x in the exponent and a sqrt x, and I'm not sure how to simplify things.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, you should include your attempt to solve the problem and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: This looks like a solution to a differential equation. Why is an explicit form needed for x in terms of y?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the guidance. I put down a few thoughts, but I can't get too far: I don't know how to simplify equations when there is an x in an exponent and a sqrt x.

Comment: randomgirl - the equation describes a real life process in which I know y but I don't know x. I'm using this in an optimization model in which y will be varying and so I'll be continually recalculating x.

Comment: My guess is that you won't be able to solve to $x$ in a nice way since it is an exponential plus a power function. You might try it with software.

Comment: Thanks - I was afraid of that. Is  there software that will solve the equation for x in a general way, or are you talking about plugging in numbers and solving on a case by case basis?